# In Fortran, is the stop intrinsic expected to print a 'STOP' in standard output?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I often use the `stop` intrinsic in Fortran to stop the execution for various reasons (mainly after fails in tests).

```
program test1
    stop
end program
```

does not do anything but stop the program execution.

```
program test2
    stop 'hello'
end program
```

prints in the standard output :

> STOP hello

I never noticed this behavior before. Is this "STOP" expected before "hello" in the output? or is it a compiler bug or ...?

My compiler is `gfortran --version`:

```
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug.  The Fortran standard specifies that it is up to the Fortran processor how the stop code is "made available".  It recommends the use of formatted output to the error unit, but the format (in a general sense) can be whatever the compiler authors thought best.